# Examine generic type of a method parameter

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I don't know whether this can be done in Java. I can't find a solution for it.

I want to examine all methods in a class and find out how the parameters of the method looks like with the generic info. If for example you have an interface and an implementer like the following:

```
// Services are the objects i will examine

public interface Service<T extends DetailsModel> {
   public Response findObject(RequestEvent<T> event);
}

public interface SomeObjectService extends Service<SomeObject> {
   Response findObject(RequestEvent<SomeObject> event);
}

public class SomeObjectServiceImpl extends SomeObjectService  {
   public Response findObject(RequestEvent<SomeObject> event) {...}
}

// Events are the parameters of the services

public interface Event<T extends DetailsModel> {
   Callback getCallback()
}

public abstract class AbstractEvent<T> implements Event<T> {

  public Callback getCallback() {
     return null;
  }
}

public class RequestEvent<T> extends AbstractEvent<T> {
    Handle<T> t;

    public Handle<T> getHandle() {...}
}
```

I have tried all kind of things to get the actual T out of RequestEvent when looking at SomeObjectServiceImpl. For example

```
public <D extends DetailsModel> void configure(Service<D> service) {
   Method[] allDeclaredMethods = service.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();

   for (Method declaredMethod : allDeclaredMethods) {
     try {
        Type[] parameterTypes = declaredMethod.getGenericParameterTypes();
        if (parameterTypes.length == 1) {
           Type parameterType = parameterTypes[0];
           if (Event.class.isAssignableFrom((Class<?>) parameterType)) {
              ParameterizedType type = ((ParameterizedType) ((Class) parameterType).getGenericSuperclass());
              Type genericType = type.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
              if (genericType != null && genericType instanceof Class) {
                 EventDescriber eventDescriber = new EventDescriber(
                       (Class<? extends Event>) parameterType,
                       (Class) genericType);
              }
           }
        } 
     } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.warn("Could not map " + declaredMethod, e);
     }
  }
```

Then I would like the result of examing the methods in SomeObjectServiceImpl to be something like:

```
ServiceImpl:
  findObject: 
     RequestEvent
        SomeObject (I cant find this. Instead I find a TypeVariableImpl.)
```

Can you do this with java reflection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it's possible. Use the `Method` to retrieve [generic parameter types][1].

```
Method method = ServiceImpl.class.getMethod("doSomething",
            DoSomethingEvent.class);
ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType)method.getGenericParameterTypes()[0];
```

Then access the [raw type][2] and the [actual type arguments][3].

```
type.getRawType();
type.getActualTypeArguments()[0]; // first type argument
```

---

Here's a working example

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        configure(new ServiceImpl());
    }

    public static <T> void configure(Service<T> service) {
        Method[] allDeclaredMethods = service.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();

        for (Method declaredMethod : allDeclaredMethods) {
            try {
                Class<?>[] parameterTypes = declaredMethod.getParameterTypes();
                if (parameterTypes.length == 1) {
                    Class<?> parameterType = parameterTypes[0];
                    if (Event.class.isAssignableFrom(parameterType)) {
                        ParameterizedType type = ((ParameterizedType) declaredMethod
                                .getGenericParameterTypes()[0]);
                        Type typeArgument = type.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
                        System.out.println("Parameter type: " + type.getRawType() + ", Generic type argument: " + typeArgument);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

interface Response {
}

interface Service<T> {
    public Response findObject(RequestEvent<T> event);
}

class ServiceImpl implements Service<SomeObject> {
    public Response findObject(RequestEvent<SomeObject> event) {
        return null;
    }

    public Response doSomething(DoSomethingEvent<SomethingAction> event) {
        return null;
    }
}

interface Event<T> {
}

interface SomethingAction {
}

class SomeObject {
}

class DoSomethingEvent<T> extends RequestEvent<T> {
}

interface Handle<T> {
}

class RequestEvent<T> implements Event<T> {
    Handle<T> t;

    public Handle<T> getHandle() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

It prints

```
Parameter type: class com.example.RequestEvent, Generic type argument: class com.example.SomeObject
Parameter type: class com.example.DoSomethingEvent, Generic type argument: interface com.example.SomethingAction
```

Comment: @AnAmuser Which `Method` did you retrieve?

Comment: That doesn't work either. type.getActualTypeArguments()[0] returns a TypeVariableImpl(name="T", bounds=null, ...). This happens on both methods. And I use new ServiceImpl().getClass().getMethod(..) if that makes a difference.

Comment: @AnAmuser What is `ModelServiceImpl`? I'm going off of what you have in your question.

Comment: @AnAmuser Then there's a difference between what you are trying and what you've shown. Edit your question and add _exactly_ what you are doing and the types involved.

Comment: @AnAmuser You're leaving out important information. How did you get `allDeclaredMethods`? Why are you calling `getGenericSuperclass()`?

Comment: The problem is that the parameter is a Class and not a ParameterizedType. Therefore I call getGenericSuperclass() which gets me the AbstractEvent<T> class, but still only with a TypeVariableImpl. Also when I access the rawtype before the type arguments.

Comment: @AnAmuser I feel like you haven't read my answer. You're invoking `getParameterTypes` instead of `getGenericParameterTypes`. And for some reason invoking `getGenericSuperclass` on those types. Why?

Comment: I just tried It. It doesn't matter how i fetch the parameters. I tried exactly what you suggested (and a lot more than that). Have you tried debugging this.

Comment: @AnAmuser Check it out.

Comment: Hi again. I found out that the problem is that Spring makes a Proxy wrapper around the service, and that class can't give me that info, or maybe i am just too stupid. This works if I use the unproxied class.

Comment: @AnAmuser If you're involving proxies, then we may have a different story. You may want to ask another question with those details.

Answer (score 0):

I just done the same thing. Limited to `Iterable`, but the reflection code would be quite similar:

```
/**
 * Assuming the given method returns or takes an Iterable<T>, this determines the type T.
 * T may or may not extend WindupVertexFrame.
 */
private static Class typeOfIterable(Method method, boolean setter)
{
    Type type;
    if (setter) {
        Type[] types = method.getGenericParameterTypes();
        // The first parameter to the method expected to be Iterable<...> .
        if (types.length == 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Given method has 0 params: " + method);
        type = types[0];
    }
    else {
        type = method.getGenericReturnType();
    }

    // Now get the parametrized type of the generic.
    if (!(type instanceof ParameterizedType))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Given method's 1st param type is not parametrized generic: " + method);
    ParameterizedType pType = (ParameterizedType) type;
    final Type[] actualArgs = pType.getActualTypeArguments();
    if (actualArgs.length == 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Given method's 1st param type is not parametrized generic: " + method);

    Type t = actualArgs[0];
    if (t instanceof Class)
        return (Class<?>) t;

    if (t instanceof TypeVariable){
        TypeVariable tv =  (TypeVariable) actualArgs[0];
        AnnotatedType[] annotatedBounds = tv.getAnnotatedBounds();///
        GenericDeclaration genericDeclaration = tv.getGenericDeclaration();///
        return (Class) tv.getAnnotatedBounds()[0].getType();
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown kind of type: " + t.getTypeName());
}
```